# Class 'Memcached' not found not.not working in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have PHP 5.4 on a litespeed web server. PHP has been compiled properly with memcached module and we also installed properly memcached library.
In fact the problem suddenly happened without any change at all (server side) when I run the artisan command, I am getting this error:
PHP Fatal error: Class 'Memcached' not found in /laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/MemcachedConnector.php on line 52
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Class 'Memcached' not found
I googled the issue but was unable to find a solution. I am using Laravel 5.0.
I edited the app/Http/Routes.php and returned new Memcached and the php object was returned properly...
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if any can implement Memcached in laravel and wamp server vesion 7.0 + windows 7 64bit then please help me.i am tired to this implementation.

Comment: Do you have memcached php extension (module) installed?

Comment: yes,i installed Memcached extension and also edit php.ini file but still getting error.

Comment: It seems something is wrong with namespace, try to make sure your namespaces are ok

Comment: Can you show us the output of `php -m`?

Comment: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/29976/install-pear-on-windows-7-64x-using-wamp/
I follow this steps but still not done properly.

if you have steps for Memcached configuration then give me, please.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same issue.

Replace in `.env`  file:

```
From : CACHE_DRIVER=memcached<br/>
To : CACHE_DRIVER=file**
```

then clear cache : `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: yes, but i need to use memcached functionality so that is required for me.

Comment: install memcached server along with memcache php extension

Comment: ya, i am installed memcached server but laravel 5.3 is not working porperly bcz it's package name and laravel memcache class name somthing wrong so that's why not accessible in laravel 5.3 or up framework not worked.
thanks for giving ans #Pranat Srivastava.